# visual C++ and u8 prefix

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I was writting a HTTP server in visual studio preview, and I add `<meta charset="utf-8">` to use UTF-8 as content encoding.

The problem is when I use [u8 prefix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=msvc-170) on string literal, the browser looks like has encoding error.

when I remove `u8` prefix, the browser show  correctly.

Why?

and my document was save with *utf-8 (code page 65001)*

string with `u8` prefix

[image]

string without `u8` prefix

[image]

**EDIT**

update example code

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define U8

#ifdef U8
typedef const char8_t c;
c str[] = u8"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n<h1>\xf0\x9f\x93\x9d</h1>";
#else
typedef const char c;
c str[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n<h1>\xf0\x9f\x93\x9d</h1>";
#endif

template <ULONG N>
constexpr ULONG cstrlen(c(&)[N]) {
    return N - 1;
}

int main() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET listener, s;
    CHAR buf[1024 * 3];
    WSABUF wsabuf{ .len = sizeof(buf), .buf = buf };
    DWORD bytes, flags = 0;
    const char* err = "?";
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData)) {
        err = "WSAStartup";
        goto Err;
    }
    {
        struct addrinfo hints = {};
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
        struct addrinfo* result;
        if (getaddrinfo(NULL, "80", &hints, &result)) {
            err = "getaddrinfo";
            goto Err;
        }
        listener = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | WSA_FLAG_NO_HANDLE_INHERIT);
        if (listener == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            err = "WSASocket";
            goto Err;
            
        }
        if (bind(listener, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            err = "bind";
            closesocket(listener);
            goto Err;
        }
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        if (listen(listener, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            err = "listen";
            closesocket(listener);
            goto Err;
        }
    }
    puts("Ready...");
    for (;;) {
        s = WSAAccept(listener, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            closesocket(listener);
            err = "WSAAccept";
            goto Err;
        }
        wsabuf.len = sizeof(buf);
        wsabuf.buf = buf;
        bytes = flags = 0;
        if (WSARecv(s, &wsabuf, 1, &bytes, &flags, NULL, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            err = "WSARecv";
            goto Err;
        }
        wsabuf.buf = (char*)str;
        wsabuf.len = cstrlen(str);
        if (WSASend(s, &wsabuf, 1, &bytes, 0, NULL, NULL)) {
            err = "WSASend";
            closesocket(s);
            goto Err;
        }
        closesocket(s);
    }
    return 0;
Err:
    puts(err);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
```

run with `std=c++20`

Comment: Please show a [mcve] (code that we can compile and run without making any change). Don't post the whole web server, create a short reproduction. If you can print these strings on the console and the output is different with and without u8, post that.

Comment: did you save as UTF-8 with or without BOM? without BOM you'll need the the [`/utf-8` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=msvc-170)

Comment: I save without BOM

Comment: I add `/utf-8` to Additional Options, it has no effect

Comment: My guess would be that your `\x` literals are being treated as individual characters and separately utf-8 encoded. Try using `\u` literals instead

Comment: @AlanBirtles  I replace with `\U0001f4dd`, and it works in `u8` and no `u8`!  thanks

Comment: @AlanBirtles "\x literals are being treated as individual characters and separately utf-8 encoded." [This seems like the case](https://godbolt.org/z/eEe76chzo), but it means MSVC is broken. These escape sequences should not be encoded (from what? these are not utf-8 characters), but inserted to the string as is. Having said that, the \u escape should be preferred over \x anyway, so this is the right solution.

Comment: why are you using `\U0001f4dd` instead of `""` directly?

Comment: @phuclv    does not work, too.And when I use unicode escape, I can save my documents as portable  ascii.

Comment: And that clearly means I am using Unicode, not my local code page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @AlanBirtles, use `\u` literal solve my problem.

`u8` and no `u8` both works in `\U0001f4dd`

update code

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define U8

#ifdef U8
typedef const char8_t c;
c str[] = u8"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n<h1>\U0001f4dd</h1>";
#else
typedef const char c;
c str[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n<h1>\U0001f4dd</h1>";
#endif const char c;

template <ULONG N>
constexpr ULONG cstrlen(c(&)[N]) {
    return N - 1;
}

int main() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET listener, s;
    CHAR buf[1024 * 3];
    WSABUF wsabuf{ .len = sizeof(buf), .buf = buf };
    DWORD bytes, flags = 0;
    const char* err = "?";
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData)) {
        err = "WSAStartup";
        goto Err;
    }
    {
        struct addrinfo hints = {};
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
        struct addrinfo* result;
        if (getaddrinfo(NULL, "80", &hints, &result)) {
            err = "getaddrinfo";
            goto Err;
        }
        listener = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | WSA_FLAG_NO_HANDLE_INHERIT);
        if (listener == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            err = "WSASocket";
            goto Err;
        }
        if (bind(listener, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            err = "bind";
            closesocket(listener);
            goto Err;
        }
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        if (listen(listener, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            err = "listen";
            closesocket(listener);
            goto Err;
        }
    }
    puts("Ready...");
    for (;;) {
        s = WSAAccept(listener, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            closesocket(listener);
            err = "WSAAccept";
            goto Err;
        }
        wsabuf.len = sizeof(buf);
        wsabuf.buf = buf;
        bytes = flags = 0;
        if (WSARecv(s, &wsabuf, 1, &bytes, &flags, NULL, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            err = "WSARecv";
            goto Err;
        }
        wsabuf.buf = (char*)str;
        wsabuf.len = cstrlen(str);
        if (WSASend(s, &wsabuf, 1, &bytes, 0, NULL, NULL)) {
            err = "WSASend";
            closesocket(s);
            goto Err;
        }
        closesocket(s);
    }
    return 0;
Err:
    puts(err);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
```